# error: invalid initializer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char prosto;
    char line[256];

    argv[1] = "cat.txt";

    char path2[10000];
    getcwd(path2, 10000);
    char path1[10000] = strcat(path1, "\\");
    FILE *file;
    char *path = strcat(path1, argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", path2);
    printf("%s\n", path1);
    printf("%s", path);
}
```

```
error: invalid initializer
   21 |     char path1[10000] = strcat(path1, "\\");
      |                         ^~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Посмотри что и куда ты в этой строчке присваиваешь

Comment: @Эникейщик исправил на char path1[10000] = strcat(path2, "\\"); но ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 2):

```
char path1[10000] = strcat(path1, "\\");
```

Здесь вы вызываете функцию конкатенации строки, которая не инициализирована и она хранит только мусор памяти. Сначала берём путь директории :

```
char path2[10000];
getcwd(path2, 10000);
char path1[10000] ;
```

В строке `path2` у вас уже путь к текущей директории. А в строке `path1` пока ещё ничего нет. Сначала надо скопировать строку с путём в этот новый массив.

```
strncpy ( path1 , path2 , 10000 ) ;
```

Потом к этой строке добавить слеш.

```
strcat(path1, "\\");
```

*Но можно и без второго массива работать, просто использовать только `path2`.*

Comment: Возможно лучше вместо strcpy/strcat использовать один [snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)

Answer (score -3):

Достаточно было изменить `char path1[10000] = strcat(path1, "\\");`
на
`char *path1 = strcat(path1, "\\");`

Comment: Скомпилируется, но абсолютно мертворождено

Comment: "Компилируется" и "правильно работает" — две большие разницы...